# How to test the type of variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, type-conversion

Assume that two variables, varA and varB, are assigned values, either numbers or strings.

Write a piece of Python code that prints out one of the following messages:

> "string involved" if either varA or varB are strings
>
> "bigger" if varA is larger than varB
>
> "equal" if varA is equal to varB
>
> "smaller" if varA is smaller than varB

Write your code in the following box assuming `varA` and `varB` are already defined.

My code is

```
if type(varA) == type('s')) or (type(varB) == type('s')):
    print "string involved"
if int(varA)>int(varB):
    print "bigger"
elif (int(varA)<int(varB)):
    print "smaller"
else:
    print "equal"
```

Test Values: `varA = -7`, `varB = adieu`
Output is:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'adieu'
```

Why I am getting this output? How to solve this issue?

Comment: By `varB = adieu` do you mean `varB = 'adieu'`? Why are you using `type` equality rather than e.g. `isinstance(varA, basestring)`?

Comment: int(varA) tries to convert your string to an int. Which is not possible if your first condition is True.
If you change your second "if" to a "elif" it won't try this anymore

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip the second test if the first test is true. One of your arguments is a string, and that string cannot be converted to an integer because `Adieu` consists of letters, not digits.

You can do so with using `elif` instead of `if`:

```
if type(varA) == type('s')) or (type(varB) == type('s')):
    print "string involved"
elif int(varA)>int(varB):
    print "bigger"
elif (int(varA)<int(varB)):
    print "smaller"
else:
    print "equal"
```

You don't need to convert `varA` and `varB` to integers at all here though, because your *first* test already determined that neither are strings, and I happen to know the assignment you are doing only passes in strings or integers:

```
if type(varA) == type('s')) or (type(varB) == type('s')):
    print "string involved"
elif varA > varB:
    print "bigger"
elif varA < varB:
    print "smaller"
else:
    print "equal"
```

Next, you don't have to use `type('s')` when you can reference the outcome of that test directly by using `str`; if you are going to use `type()`, you should test for *identity* instead of equality here:

```
if type(varA) is str or type(varB) is str:
    print "string involved"
elif int(varA)>int(varB):
    print "bigger"
elif (int(varA)<int(varB)):
    print "smaller"
else:
    print "equal"
```

It is almost always better to use `isinstance()` to test for types though, as this allows for *subclasses* to pass the test too:

```
if type(varA) == type('s')) or (type(varB) == type('s')):
    print "string involved"
elif varA > varB:
    print "bigger"
elif varA < varB:
    print "smaller"
else:
    print "equal"
```

Next, you don't have to use `type('s')` when you can reference the outcome of that test directly by using `str`; if you are going to use `type()`, you should test for *identity* instead of equality here:

```
if isinstance(varA, str) or isinstance(varB, str):
    print "string involved"
elif varA > varB:
    print "bigger"
elif varA < varB:
    print "smaller"
else:
    print "equal"
```

I strongly suspect your assignment asks you to create a function that **returns** the outcome, not print. In that case you need to use a `return` statement instead:

```
if isinstance(varA, str) or isinstance(varB, str):
    return "string involved"
elif varA > varB:
    return "bigger"
elif varA < varB:
    return "smaller"
else:
    return "equal"
```